# javascript syntax and jQuery source

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [For the function (function($){})(), I’ve seen it with the word jQuery in it, why is that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090284/for-the-function-function-ive-seen-it-with-the-word-jquery-in-it-why)

Can someone explain the following syntax that is used in the jQuery source files? I am learning jQuery and trying to dive into writing a jquery.ui.widget.

```
(function ($)
{
    ... code ...
} (jQuery));
```

While I am using jQuery, this is really just a JavaScript question, I guess.

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: See a similar question from yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090284/for-the-function-function-ive-seen-it-with-the-word-jquery-in-it-why

Comment: Indeed JavaScript-related, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643321/javascript-why-the-anonymous-function-wrapper among many others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This defines an anonymous function with one argument, called `$`, then invokes the function passing `jQuery` as the argument.

Answer (score 1):

It's called the self executing anonymous function. No different than any other function call except the function is a literal ( doesnt have a name ), is wrapped in parens to make it a valid expression and then invoked.

```
function blah($){};
blah(jQuery);
```

is the same as that piece of code, it creates a private namespace in which the window.jQuery object is passed and referenced within the function body as `$` to prevent namespace collisions.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of the [JavaScript module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth).