# Basic jQuery: what is the point of a wrapper?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does (function($) {})(jQuery); mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937227/what-does-function-jquery-mean)
>   [For the function (function($){})(), I've seen it with the word jQuery in it, why is that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090284/for-the-function-function-ive-seen-it-with-the-word-jquery-in-it-why)

I've seen this used in many places, and I understand that some code ill not work without it... but I have no idea what it does: what is the purpose of this wrapper?

```
(function($){  

     ...

})(jQuery);
```

An explanation and/or direction to some good resources would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: now where is the dupe for this one...

Comment: it's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598479/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-anonymous-function-wrapper-in-jquery

Comment: darn, yours is a better dupe, which i could change my vote.

Comment: thank you! need to improve my searching skills :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It defines a scope for what's inside the function body, keeping it out of the global namespace, while defining `$` as an alias for `jQuery`.